# Moving SQL Server CE data into SQL Server for edits and back

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-ce

Want to know the fastest, productive and easiest way to move a SQL Server CE database into SQL Server
and after some processes return it back, or export it as a new compact local database.

What proven procedure have you experienced and suggest ?

- **Version :** SQL Server CE 3.5
- **Version :** SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried replication? here you may find an almost complete article upon syncing 2008r2 and CE:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ff928494.aspx

Comment: I wanted to know some exact experiences on the topic, but anyway that's enough for now, maybe find something useful. thanks ...